# Increasing a variable by one without using a function

Tags: excel

I have the following problem with excel. I want to increase a variable by one without using a function. So i mean without writing a "=" before my expression. Example:

B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(i)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(1)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(2)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(3)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(4)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(5)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(6)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(7)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(8)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(9)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(10)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(11)
B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(12)

.......

I must do that for many expressions and for i > 500. So i can't do that by hand. I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to generate a lot of formulae in Excel, which isn't really the focus of this site.

Comment: No, i just want to increase i in the expression by one in each line.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing here.  Are these "expressions" worksheet formulas, or are you working in VBA ?  Typically you might use a For...Next loop for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with a function, then "copy" and select "paste as...". In the sub menu select the radiobutton in front of "values". Your formulas are now overwritten by the actual values.

Comment: Sincerly, it doesn't work. I can't just write f(x) = B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(A1), B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(A2)...... The expression B1.c_O2_L_y.Value() does not exist in the excel file and i get an error.

Comment: If I am getting it right, you just want to have the output that is displayed in your initial post, but then for over 500 cells?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your function is wrong. Try something like

```
=CONCATENATE("B1.c_O2_L_y.Value(",ROW(),")")
```